# Can't boot RPI4

Tags: boot, boot-issues, bootloader

My raspberry pi 4 don't seems to boot anymore (tried different SD card, OS, power adaptor)
The red led next to the power (USB-C) remain static red.
The green led next to it blink 8x
when I plug to a screen I have sometime some random vertical green light, sometime a full red screen.
I try to create a SD card using Raspberry Pi Imager and misc utility images > USB Boot but that's does seems to boot (tried with SD and USB)
I also tried without the hat same issue, and tried with a SD card which work on a another Raspberry Pi 4, same

[Video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zh7Tmk3_WJo)

Comment: same as https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/124704/raspberry-pi-4-bricked

Comment: I don't want to edit the whole post

Comment: I'm just pointing out this this the same issue, you don't need to ask the same question again - anyway, if you're doing everything right, flashing the image on multiple SD cards, booting with absolutely no HATS, and the pi flashes 8 times like that ... I'd say it's dead

Answer (score 0):

This happened yesterday when I was moving my RPi 4. Unplug and replug all of the cables connecting to the Pi and try again. (For me shaking the mouse also helps when I turn on my Pi.)